# Existence of a continuous function in a coarser space

Tags: general-topology

Let $g$ be a continuous one-to-one onto map from a Tychonoff space $X$ to a separable metric space $Y$. If $V$ is an open subset of $Y$ and $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous map. Is it possible to find a continuous map $F:Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  such that $F(V)=f(g^{-1}(V))$?

Answer (score 2):

You can take $Y=V$ to be some connected separable metric space with more than one point and $X$ to be $Y$ with the discrete topology, and then $f(g^{-1}(V))$ can be any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ but $F(V)$ must always be an interval by connectedness of $Y$.